# How to replace the xml text to use Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm making xml editor, and want to replace the text in the xml file

```
data.xml
...
<country name="Singapore">
        <gdppc>text<bold>text</bold>this</gdppc>
</country>
...
```

I want to change "this" to "text", use to python 2.X

Comment: What do you mean with "this" to "text"? Could you provide an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **replace()** method.

```
xml_code = """data.xml
...
<country name="Singapore">
        <gdppc>text<bold>text</bold>this</gdppc>
</country>
..."""

edited_xml_code = xml_code.replace("this", "text")

print(edited_xml_code)
```